# What's the best way to filter a pandas series and then set the values of the part selected?

Tags: select, pandas, filtering, series, setvalue

For example I have a series like this:

```
AFalse    0.220522 
BTrue    -1.050370
CFalse   -1.202922
DTrue     0.950305
EFalse    0.003110
FTrue     1.115483
GFalse    0.767281
HTrue    -1.376692
IFalse    1.729867
JTrue     2.574027
dtype: float64
```

I want to filter out only the rows with 'True' and set the values to None. What's the best way to do so from a speed stand point? I will be running this operation a few million times. Thanks.

Comment: Do the `True`  and `False` rows always alternate?

Comment: How was this Series built? If you could keep the `A,B,C`s separate from the `True`, `False`s during the construction of the Series, then selection of the `True` rows could be done faster.

Comment: The series here is just an example. The actual series is a limit order book snap shot, which has names 'bid.1.price', 'bid.2.price' ..., 'ask.1.price', 'ask.2.price' ..., and I would like to be able to alter the values of such entries based on a fast selection scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a random series:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(4), index=idx, name='test')
```

Create a mask on the index using list comprehension.  Note that 'True' can be anywhere within the index value.  Then use .loc to set the value as you have already done.

```
idx = ['True' in i for i in s.index]
s.loc[idx] = None  # or np.NaN

>>> s
Out[50]: 
ATrue          None
BFalse    0.9134165
CTrue          None
DFalse    0.2530273
Name: test, dtype: object
```

Comment: Very similar to what I have myself, but I believe this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using vectorized operations will help with speed. Starting with your `Series` as s

```
df = s.reset_index()
mask = df['index'].str.contains('True')
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = None
df.set_index('index')['a']
```

returns

```
index
AFalse    0.220522
BTrue          NaN
CFalse   -1.202922
DTrue          NaN
EFalse    0.003110
FTrue          NaN
GFalse    0.767281
HTrue          NaN
IFalse    1.729867
JTrue          NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The method works, but the operation creates a new df, which would greatly impact my memory usage. When doing large number of this operation, this would impact code performance. is there a way to filter out a view of the series and set it's values, instead of creating a copy of the series?

Comment: This is the best I have:

`idxs = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('True'),s.index)`

`s.loc[idxs] = None`